# Setting up Django settings for sphinx (documentation)

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I have a Django app I'm trying to set up documentation for. The directory structure is as follows:

```
- doc
- project
| - manage.py
```

I have set up the paths so that Sphinx can see things, but when I try to use autodoc, some of the settings I've set in settings.py aren't available. Here's how I'm setting up the environment, what am I doing wrong?

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from project import settings

setup_environ(settings, 'project.settings')
```

Comment: Are some settings documented while other settings are not? Can you show us (a relevant portion of) the settings.py file?

Comment: Where exactly are you setting up that environment? If it is in your Sphinx's `conf.py`, ok. If they're in another file (like manage.py), sphinx might not have read them.

Comment: @brian-hicks, do you have any update on where you have that env setup code?

Comment: @ReinoutvanRees, it's in `conf.py`. I ended up specifying `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in the command to build the docs.

Comment: Ok. I don't have a sure-fire answer, but I did add one with whatever I could come up with as a possible cause. And a solution, should you need it in a further project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only think of two causes of why the `setup_environ()` call in your Sphinx's `conf.py` does not work:

- It does not do its magic early enough. You import other things that already need the settings *before* that line.
- The settings.py itself is importing too much. Would be weird if this is the case, though.

Note that `setup_environ()` is deprecated. It won't be removed till Django 1.6, though.

Another option is to use `os.environ` right at the top of your `conf.py` script. You're guaranteed to be in time there :-)

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
```

Comment: I did the equivalent of this by running the command while specifying `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. This would have worked as well.